# Resize Calculated Height on AutoSize of TextArea, to work ideally? (jsfiddle - updated)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There's this great autosize plugin for textareas by http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ and I'd like to use it in the #appear section of this: http://jsfiddle.net/45p1pgo6/5/ ..but right now pressing the 'enter' key to break the line causes the #content section to move downward, and so the #footer moves out of the window..

How do I edit this javascript to recalculate the height of #appear, to actively adjust the height of #content? ..such that the layout is maintained: #header remains visible no matter what, #content decreases in size in parallel to the increase in height of #appear, which would ideally increase in height until the #header reaches the #footer that remains sticky to the bottom, at which point the textarea in #appear would start scrolling..

I tested made an attempt in writing the following snippet, and it logs seemingly accurate numbers for the heights, but the footer leaves the window at first, and then the footer moves up (when it should stay sticky to the bottom) .. and while the content is decreasing in size, and the footer curiously winds up in the middle.. http://jsfiddle.net/45p1pgo6/8/

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#expand-textarea', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 108) { // when the enter key is pressed

    console.log('keypress of enter on #expand-textarea..');

    var $appear = $('#appear');
    var $content = $('#content');
    var animateHeight = 0;

    var $expandTextarea = $('#expand-textarea');
    var textareaHeight = $expandTextarea.height(); // get the textarea height
    console.log('textareaHeight = ' + textareaHeight);

    appearHeight = $appear.height();    // to get the height of #appear
    animateHeight = appearHeight + textareaHeight;
    console.log('animateHeight = ' + animateHeight);

    $content.css({height: "calc(100% - "+ animateHeight +"px)"});

  }

});
```

Here's the code that this is meant to be an extension of..am new to some of this syntax:

```
$("#view").on("click", "#header", function () {
  var $appear = $('#appear');
  var io = this.io ^= 1; // Toggler

  $appear.show();               // Temporarily show
  var animH = $appear.height(); // Get height and
  if(io) $appear.hide();        // fast hide.

  $('#content').animate({       // Animate content height
      height: (io?"-=":"+=")+animH
    },{
      step: function() {
        $(this).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
      },
      complete : function(){
        var h = 88 + (io?animH:0); // header+footer = 88px
        $(this).css({height: "calc(100% - "+ h +"px)"});
      }
   });

  $appear.slideToggle();        // Now do it with animation

});
```

Comment: Why are you using `#expand-textarea` inside the function and `.expand-textarea` in in the keypress? Is the textarea set with `expand-textarea` in both the class and id?

Comment: @Michael_B yeh that was a typo.. revised accordingly

Comment: The problem doesn't manifest itself here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyv6zpu3/8/

Comment: @Michael_B right..because http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ isn't an available dependency on jsbin.. As mentioned, is there a way to upload it to show the effect? Otherwise it would have to tested locally to really understand the issue..

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks again for your thoughts on this..would be really great to have a solution

Comment: I don't know how to solve a problem I don't see. Maybe you could edit the jsfiddle to produce the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @Michael_B understandable..I just found cdnjs.com, so the autosize.js is now included here: http://jsfiddle.net/45p1pgo6/5/

Comment: @Michael_B as you can see, the content is not adjusting in height in place, and the footer gets pushed out of the window. If you delete everything in the textarea, the footer then moves up out of bottom-stickiness too..

Answer (score 0):

To start with, it appears you have some syntax errors:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#expand-textarea', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 108) { // when the enter key is pressed

    console.log('keypress of enter on #expand-textarea..');

    var $appear = $('#appear');
    var $content = $('#content');
    var animateHeight = 0;

    var $expandtextarea = $('#expand-textarea');//<--Cant hyphenate variables;
    var textareaHeight = $expandtextarea.height();//<--Missing ';' and cant hyphenate variables
        // get the textarea height
    console.log('textareaHeight = ' + textareaHeight);

    appearHeight = $appear.height();    // to get the height of #appear
    animateHeight = appearHeight + textareaHeight;
    console.log('animateHeight = ' + animateHeight);

    $content.css({height: "calc(100% - "+ animateHeight +"px)"})//<--Missing ';'

  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but this still doesn't work.. those were typos lost in the post, but are actually in the source code..